# MercurialEclipse icons after pull

Tags: mercurial, pull, mercurialeclipse

I'm new to Mercurial and MercurialEclipse, and I think I'm not quite understanding this:
After I pull from the central repository (with `Update After Pull` selected), it is my understanding that all files are loaded form the central repo to my local repo. However, after I pull, I'm seeing the following:

[image]

Doesn't the star icon indicate that there are differences between my local copy and the central copy?
What am I missing here? How do I make sure that my files are the most recent copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking on your Eclipse project and select Team --> Refresh Status. I often have to do that for the status icons to be updated.

**Edit**: if you want to override all local changes, select the checkbox "Clean update (override local changes)" in the Pull dialog of Eclipse.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, but good to know - thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

When you update it merges the local changes you have with the changes in the revision you are updating to. In the update dialog if you select the "force" checkbox it will revert any uncommitted changes. Other ways to remove your local changes are updating by right clicking on a revision in the history view and selecting "switch to", or use the "revert" dialog.

Comment: I don't see a "force" checkbox when I pull via Eclipse. So a normal pull doesn't revert changes? It sounds like I'd need to merge after a pull.